# Command line to map webDav-drive?

Tags: windows-10, webdav

My current command line is:

`net use z: \\site.com@5005/p  /user:user user`

With it i can successfully log on and view the contents of the share, but the files don't behave right and are not copy-able. All is well if i use a utility to map the drive.

What would be the right command line?

Comment: What permissions do you have on the remote file system?

Comment: it varies. but permissions at least for file-viewing seem to behave correctly. if i log on as admin, i'll see all the files, if a user, then just files for that user.